# Using Data Driven Pages to map based on field name in attribute table of one feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

To start, I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1, advanced.

I am developing a data driven pages product based on the number of people coming from a particular facility by ZIP code. The data driven component of this process is that there are over 40 facilities I will be doing a map for. I have a feature class containing all the ZIP codes in my state, and a field in the attribute table for each of the facilities I need a map of. Each facility field lists the number of people coming from that particular facility by ZIP code (as rows).

I have a point feature class for each of these facilities, as well as a 30 mile graphic buffer feature class (which looks like a square going 30 miles out from each facility point) that can serve as the data-driven extent. In the point and buffer features' cases, the names of the facilities are the rows, so it is easy enough to set one up to be the index layer, and the other to have a page definition based on facility name.

Is there a way to map the number of people by ZIP code from each facility, so that each data driven page maps a different field, since the field names are also the names of the facilities? Keep in mind, in this feature the rows are the ZIP code names and each fields is a facility which matches the index layer based on a point feature class of each facility.

The first image is what I need help with. The second image shows what the points and their buffers format look like, for comparison.

Is it possible to make data driven maps based on the field names matching the index layer row names?

[image: Here's an example of what I mean]
[image]

Comment: Duplicate your points to a structure with 3 fields: zip, facility, count.

Comment: can you explain more? i don't understand how that would solve my issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution on my own in a simpler way, so I thought I would share!

The original table had duplicate ZIP codes for each instance, and a count affiliate with each unique instance of a ZIP-facility observation, as shown in the pic below.

[image]

From there, I loaded this table into ArcGIS, and joined it to ZIP code centroids, so I could create new fields with X and Y coordinates. I un-joined the ZIP code centroids, then displayed XY on the table. From there, I exported the display XY events file to a new point feature class, and pulled in the ZIP polygon feature class. I used the spatial join tool (not the one where you right click on a feature), and set the target feature to the ZIP polygons, and the join feature as the centroids. The **[spatial join tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm)** has the ability to join one to many, allowing duplicates of the target feature (the polygons). The result is a polygon feature class of ZIP codes, where there are duplicate ZIP for the different facilities.

For data driven pages, as long as the Facility field can match the data driven pages' index layer, I can set a [Page Definition Query](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/map/page-layouts/using-page-definition-queries.htm) to match the index layer and only map those ZIP codes matching each page.

Comment: It is essentially my answer, great job.

Answer (score 0):

This relationship:

[image]

Can be presented your way (pivot table):

[image]

Or as a database table:

[image]

Replicate ZIP polygons, so you can use page definition query, e.g.

Page 1

[image]

and 2:

[image]

Let me know if you are able to zip your table and I'll explain how to replicate zip polygons(?)

Comment: I think this almost had it, but you did not clearly explain how to get the data in the needed format.